# Can we split the Filepath from the last folder in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

For example i have a file ISample.cs in this path like

```
"D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCE CODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\ISample.cs"
```

Here i wanna the file-path from

```
"ProceduresAll\ISample.cs"
```

Before that i don't wanna that path.Here i am using folder browser for choosing the folder.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
string path = @"D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCE CODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\ISample.cs";

//ISample.cs
Path.GetFileName(path);

//D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCE CODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL
Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

//ProceduresALL
Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
```

Use Path.Combine("ProceduresALL", "ISample.cs") to get ProceduresALL\ISample.cs (using the above to get these strings).

Answer (score 2):

```
string fullPath = @"D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCE CODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\ISample.cs";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
string shortPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetFileName(filePath), fileName)
```

`Path.GetFileName(filePath)` gets the "filename" part which is actually the last directory part as `filePath` doesn't contain a filename anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the string function Split to split on \ or you could use the LastIndexOf and Substring functions to chop away at the paths.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
var path = "D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCE CODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\ISample.cs";
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
var directoryName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryName,fileName);
```

Comment: From MSDN (`GetDirectoryName`): In most cases, the string returned by this method consists of all characters in the path up to but not including the last DirectorySeparatorChar or AltDirectorySeparatorChar.