# Split a Folder Path and File Name

Tags: c#, file, ocr, kofax

I have a Folder Path and file Name which I want to split it. The two paths are :          `F:\AutoImport - Folder\20141612\Inv.trg` and  `F:\EmailImport\rohan@yahoo.com_01-01-2014_05-05-22\Inv.trg`.

So I want to split this path and also I  just  want "Rohan" name and "20141612" from the path. Please suggest how can I achieve this in .net using C# coding.

This Name is needed to be used as a Custom Name in Kofax Capture Batch Name. As of Now the Batch Name is: 45- F:\EmailImport\ram@afcl.com_09-01-2014_10-02-30\New Text Document.trg. I also don't know from where 45- came and this Batch name is coming from a Sample script giving by Kofax.

Comment: Type C# split string into google

Comment: There are plenty of answers like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323874/can-we-split-the-filepath-from-the-last-folder-in-c Please search in before you ask a question

Comment: @JRLambert - Please don't. Use the appropriate methods from [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.aspx).

Comment: See the answer. This is what you required?

Comment: @Corak `mypath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))` returns the array, then `myPathArray.Lenth - 2` as the index of the needed folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your output. By using `String.Split()` you can easily achieve this :

```
string filepath1 = @"F:\EmailImport\rohan@yahoo.com_01-01-2014_05-05-22\Inv.trg";
System.IO.FileInfo fif = new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath1);
string folderdet = fif.Directory.Name;
string[] arr1 = folderdet.Split('@');
string myname = arr1[0];
Console.WriteLine(myname);

string filepath2 = @" F:\AutoImport - Folder\20141612\Inv.trg";
System.IO.FileInfo fileinfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath2);
string foldername = fileinfo.Directory.Name;
Console.WriteLine(foldername);
```

Check it and let me know if you have any issues.